# I can't select By name in Columns to be cleaned in azureml designer as picture I attached. How should I deal with this?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines, azure-ml-component

[image]

[image]

The data output from select columns in the dataset is not coming and because of this, I am not able to get suggestions in downstream clean missing data components. I am unable to debug why data output from select columns in dataset is not generating.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
However, it was still possible to view the column names with the "With rules" option.
By clicking on the "enter column name" text box a list with all column names appears.
You can select multiple columns in the same rule.

[image]